# merge/average neighbors closer than a given radius

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance

I have a couple hundred coordinates in a 3d space, I need to merge the points closer than a given radius and replace them with the neighbors average.

It sounds like a pretty standard problem but I haven't been able to find a solution so far. The dataset is small enough to be able to compute pairwise distances for all the points.

Don't know, maybe some kind of graph analysis / connected components labelling on the sparse distance matrix?

I don't really need the averaging part, just the clustering (is clustering the correct term here?)

A toy dataset could be `coords = np.random.random(size=(100,2))`

Here's what I tried so far using `scipy.cluster.hierarchy`. It seems to work fine, but I'm open to more suggestions (`DBSCAN` maybe?)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fclusterdata
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

np.random.seed(0)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

gs = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)
gs.update(wspace=0.01, hspace= 0.05)

coords = np.random.randint(30, size=(200,2))
img = np.zeros((30,30))
img[coords.T.tolist()] = 1

ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax.imshow(img, cmap="nipy_spectral")

clusters = fclusterdata(coords, 2, criterion="distance", metric="euclidean")
print(len(np.unique(clusters)))

img[coords.T.tolist()] = clusters

ax = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax.imshow(img, cmap="nipy_spectral")

plt.show()
```

[image: clusters]

Comment: Can you give a worked example of this: `I need to merge the points closer than a given radius and replace them with the neighbors average`?

Comment: will think about a way to make it clearer, I need to find point clusters where any point is closer to any other point than a given distance

Comment: maybe compute pairwise distances on all points, save distance and associated points and then merge depending on radius

Comment: @jpp I've updated the question with my current solution, it should make clearer what I'm after, still open to better answers or different approaches

Comment: So, what you are after is a grouping of points, such that in each group for every point there is another point in the group with distance <= radius?

Comment: @filippo if I read this correctly there may be multiple different ways to cluster a given input.

Comment: @xsquared right, but I'm also fine with single point groups if it has no neighbor

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Think about it as a graph problem, for each point you connect it with all the neighbors closer than a threshold. At the end you should have several locally connected graphs, each corresponding to a cluster. As far as I can tell the partitioning should be unique.

Comment: @filippo in 1d case, suppose you have 3 points at [1,2,3]. If the threshold is 1.5, then 1 and 3 are not in the same cluster. But 1 and 2 or 2 and 3 may be, depending on the exact definition.

Comment: Alternatively, you can recover uniqueness if points in the same cluster are connected by a sequence of edges with lengths less than a given threshold.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko I don't need full connectivity, a point is in the cluster as long as it's connected to any point in the cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that uses KDTree to query neighbors and networkx module to gather connected components.

```
from scipy import spatial
import networkx as nx

cutoff = 2

components = nx.connected_components(
    nx.from_edgelist(
        (i, j) for i, js in enumerate(
            spatial.KDTree(coords).query_ball_point(coords, cutoff)
        )
        for j in js
    )
)

clusters = {j: i for i, js in enumerate(components) for j in js}
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: very nice, I tried something like this with `csgraph.connected_components` but couldn't get it to work, didn't know about `networkx`, looks like a fun little lib